# How to get the node names under one parent node of XML in java

Tags: java, xml, selenium

I have a situation where I need to get the node names of one XML file in java.

Here I want to get all the node names under "ns0:header"

sample XML file.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="efefefff">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns0:response_card_posted_transactions xmlns:ns0="fefefefeeff">


     <ns0:header>
        <ns0:version>1.0</ns0:version>
        <ns0:msg_id>78956285</ns0:msg_id>
        <ns0:msg_type>CCPT</ns0:msg_type>
        <ns0:msg_function>REP_CARD_POSTED_TRANSACTIONS</ns0:msg_function>
        <ns0:src_application>Src_APP</ns0:src_application>
        <ns0:target_application>CPS</ns0:target_application>
        <ns0:timestamp>01/06/2020 18:09:54</ns0:timestamp>
        <ns0:tracking_id>8032695</ns0:tracking_id>
        <ns0:bank_id>RICHBANK</ns0:bank_id>
     </ns0:header>
  </ns0:response_card_posted_transactions>
```

`</SOAP-ENV:Body>`
`</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

I was trying getchildnodes() method but unable to find that.

Thanks
Nihar

Comment: Edit the question and show us the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't share your code, it is nearly impossible for me to understand the issue in your code. Here I'm sharing a simple code to parse the child node.

**Steps:**

1. First you need to go to the   `<ns0:header>` node.
2. Then, try to get all the child nodes of that parent node.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String xml = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"efefefff\"> <SOAP-ENV:Body> <ns0:response_card_posted_transactions xmlns:ns0=\"fefefefeeff\"> <ns0:header> <ns0:version>1.0</ns0:version> <ns0:msg_id>78956285</ns0:msg_id> <ns0:msg_type>CCPT</ns0:msg_type> <ns0:msg_function>REP_CARD_POSTED_TRANSACTIONS</ns0:msg_function> <ns0:src_application>Src_APP</ns0:src_application> <ns0:target_application>CPS</ns0:target_application> <ns0:timestamp>01/06/2020 18:09:54</ns0:timestamp> <ns0:tracking_id>8032695</ns0:tracking_id> <ns0:bank_id>RICHBANK</ns0:bank_id> </ns0:header> </ns0:response_card_posted_transactions> </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
    Document doc =
            DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder()
                    .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    Node nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns0:header").item(0);
    NodeList headerChildNodes = nl.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < headerChildNodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        if (headerChildNodes.item(i) instanceof Element)
        System.out.println("Node is : "+headerChildNodes.item(i).getNodeName());
    }

}
```

**Note: To get the child node text content simply use**

```
System.out.println("Node is : "+headerChildNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
```

**Output:**
**Node:**
[image]

**Text Content:**
[image]